# Pythonic ways to catch exceptions based on their properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, com, hresult

`pywintypes` exposes a com_error like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class com_error(Exception):
    hresult: int  # The COM hresult
    strerror: str  # The error message
    excepinfo: Optional[tuple]  # An optional EXCEPINFO tuple.
    argerror: Optional[int]  # The index of the argument in error, or (usually) None or -1

# example usage
raise com_error(
    -2147352567,
    "Exception occurred.",
    (0, "Microsoft Excel", "Cannot access 'outAddin.xlam'.", "xlmain11.chm", 0, -2146827284),
    None,
)
```

The important error number is `-2146827284` or err.hresult, this defines the type of com error.

Is there a pythonic way to catch a `com_error` where the hresult property has a particular value? Maybe by defining a custom error subclass of com_error with a specific hresult - perhaps there is an equality operator I can overload?

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for something standard, unless you're the one actively raising the exceptions and you want to have a specific class for your error code of interest.

```
try:
    # example usage
    raise com_error(
        -2147352567,
        "Exception occurred.",
        (0, "Microsoft Excel", "Cannot access 'outAddin.xlam'.", "xlmain11.chm", 0, -2146827284),
    None,
    )
except com_error as e:
    if e.hresult==-2146827284:
        # Handle this however you want
        pass
    else:
        raise e # Assuming you only want to catch the com_error with your code
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought (didn't know you could re-raise, that helps) but it would be even nicer if I could define maybe a subclass of com_error called `class file_access_error(com_error)` which only matches a com_error with the right hresult

Comment: If you have an error class E, I think it only makes sense to define a child class C(E) if you are writing code where raising C is more "complete" than raising E, but you still want your code to work with all the exceptions handling created for E. 
If I understood correctly, here you need to do the opposite: E is being raised and you need to check if the error actually "coincides" with the C class you'd like to define or not. You can use an explicit if statement as I did or wrap it in some function, but what would be the added benefit of defining C compared to checking E's attributes?